# two models in blade template in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models, model1 and model2 . I am using this models in blade template and I don't want to use controller for getting value.

```
 @php
    $school = App\Models\Model1::all()
    $department = App\Models\Model2::all()
@endphp

<select name="school">
     <option value="" selected="">school</option>
         @foreach($school as $val)
         <option value="">{{$val->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
</select>

<select name="departments">
     <option value="" selected="">department</option>
       @foreach($department as $val)
        <option value="">{{$val->name}}</option>
         @endforeach                         
</select>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '$department' (T_VARIABLE)
```

But when I call only one model, the data shows perfectly. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: This breaks the `MVC` design pattern. *Why* don't you want to use the controller for getting the value?

Comment: Get your models/data in your controller. Show them in the view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the semicolon.

```
@php
   $school = App\Models\Model1::all();
   $department = App\Models\Model2::all();
@endphp
```

Comment: Just another day. :)

Comment: Yeah just another day 